# if $\sqrt{\log_4(\log_3(\log_2(x^2-2x+a)))}$ is defined for all x={set of real numbers} then find the valid interval for "a".

Tags: inequality

if $\sqrt{\log_4(\log_3(\log_2(x^2-2x+a)))}$

the question asks to find the interval in which the valid values for "a" lies

I tried by defining the

[image]
${\log_4(\log_3(\log_2(x^2-2x+a)))}$$\ge$0

Comment: For what values of the input is a logarithm nonnegative?

Comment: MathJax hint:  putting a backslash before log (and other functions like sin) gets the correct font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  for the $\log_2$ to be defined, you must have $x^2-2x+a \gt 0$ for all $x$.  $x^2-2x+a=(x-1)^2+(a-1)$ so you need $a \gt 1$.  To have the $\log_3$ make sense, you need its argument to be positive.  What does that tell you?

Comment: which condition should I satisfy first ?

Comment: I am confused when I defined the function inside the square root and keep remoing the log ,I get different inequality and when I do  define the inner argument the inequality is different

Comment: You start from the inside, as I did.  I took care of the $\log_2$ and we have a requirement.  Now you need to find the requirement on $a$ to make the $\log_3$ work, which will give another requirement.  You need both to be satisfied.  Then, assuming this is OK, you need to make sure the argument of the $\log_4$ is positive as well.

Comment: What inequality do you get?  Without seeing the work, I can't comment on where you have a problem.

Comment: when I keep removing the log I get the inequality $x^2 -2x+a$$\ge8$

Comment: and another inequality is $x^2 -2x +a$$>0$ cant we directly conclude any answer from both these conditions

Comment: check values for each log is time consuming

Comment: It is not a simple problem. Please edit your work into the question.  I haven't done the whole problem, so cannot comment on the claim that $x^2-2x+8 \ge 0$ except that you probably need $\gt 0$ because logs are not defined at $0$.  It is much easier to check work than reproduce it, particularly because I may not do it the same way you do.

Comment: shall I put an image of my work?

Comment: i did by your way and got the answer...and found it pretty simple way

Comment: Good work.  Two nits:  when you went from the $\log_4$ to the $\log_3$ the sign should change to $\gt $.  Then the process to the circled $1$ is good.  You don't then show what values of $a$ are acceptable.  The process is correct.